# Identifying minimum and maximum value of a slider range

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to grab the minimum and maximum value of a price range.

Below is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/dhana36/b453V/2/

The ideal solution would be for me to have two inputs, one for minimum and one for maximum.  Right now there just one input that controls both.

```
  <input type="text" id="amount" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
```

JS

```
$(function() {
    $('select').change(function(){
     $( "#amount" ).val( $('select').val() + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
      " - "+ $('select').val() + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
    })
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
      range: true,
      min: 0,
      max: 500,
      values: [ 75, 300 ],
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( $('select').val() + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - "+ $('select').val() + ui.values[ 1 ] );
      }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( $('select').val() + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
      " - "+ $('select').val() + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<input type="text" id="min">
<input type="text" id="max">
```

javascript

```
$(function() {
 $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
  range: true,
  min: 0,
  max: 500,
  values: [ 75, 300 ],
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
      $("#min").val($('select').val() + ui.values[ 0 ]);
      $("#max").val($('select').val() + ui.values[ 1 ]);
  },
  create: function (event, ui){
     $("#min").val($("#slider-range").slider("values")[0]);
     $("#max").val($("#slider-range").slider("values")[1]);
  }
 });    
});
```

Comment: hi thanks for your responve. i've notice for it to work though this has to be considered <select name=currency class=f15>
     <option value="$" selected>USD</option>
     <option value="&#2547;" >BDT</option>
     </select> &nbsp;  i accidently left those lines in the fiddle but it does not taking into account the currency selection,

Comment: hi Jonathan, would you like to include the currency in the input values ?

Comment: thanks for your response. no i would like to completly disregard the currency as the select line with usd, was added by mistake. the price range would only taking into consideration the min and max value

Comment: Change :   $( "#min" ).val( $('select').val() + ui.values[ 0 ]); to$( "#min" ).val( ui.values[ 0 ]);    and    $( "#max" ).val( $('select').val() + ui.values[ 1 ]);   to   $( "#max" ).val( ui.values[ 1 ]);

Comment: thanks this is the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/b453V/50/ the slider seems to be stuck

Comment: You forgot tu pass the "ui "var  to the slide function :     slide: function( event, ui )

Comment: thank you my last concern is that i would like to display initial minimum and maximum value as right now it only shows value once you start sliding but when the page loads i would want to show its initial min and ma